# How to extract and copy data annotations from one class to another (collection of properties)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, reflection, data-annotations

I've problem with reflection, DataAnnotations and asp.mvc.

I've defined interface like:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then I am creating classes that implements those interface AND adds some more properties:

```
public class a : IFoo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string P1 { get; set; }
}

public class b: IFoo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string P2 { get; set; }
}
```

*// Additional class that should store extracted properties from class a or b.*

```
public class AdditionalProperty
{
    public string Name { get; set }

    public string Value { get; set }
}
```

As you can see there are some additional properties with DataAnnotations attributes.

So the question is how to create a collection of additional properties WITH DataAnnotations metadata ?.

**I am expecting following result:**

For class a => ICollection = { { Name = "P1", Value = null } } // BUT Value property should have DataAnnotations from property P1.

For class b => ICollection = { { Name = "P2", Value = null } } // BUT Value property should have DataAnnotations from property P2.

It's required to create a model in asp.mvc with validation eg:

```
public class aspMvcModel
{
    public ICollection<AdditionalProperty> ListOfProperties { get; set; }
}
```

Then I can use this model class to display form on asp.mvc view.

--

I know how to extract list of properties and I know how to select only unique properties for each class (simplified code):

```
var classToScan = new a();
var properties = classToScan.GetType().GetProperties()
```

But I've no idea how to "copy" data annotations from one class to collection of AdditionalProperty class.

Any ideas ?.

Comment: why you want to do this? seems like you are trying to solve a wrong problem

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to understand what is your exact problem, but if you want to get all the data annotation you can use the below code. Still it will be good to mention your exact problem.

```
var metaData = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(null, Type.GetType("namespace.a"));
            IDictionary<string, object> validationAttributes = helper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes("P1", metaData);
```